# Reading most recent values in a join without performing a nested SELECT

Tags: sql, mysql, join, greatest-n-per-group, subquery

In the interest of eliminating as many nested queries as possible, I'm trying to optimize the following query:

```
   SELECT fp.id, 
          fp.user_id, 
          COUNT(c.id) AS num_replies, 
          c2.created AS latest_activity_time, c2.user_id AS latest_activity_user_id
     FROM forum_posts fp
LEFT JOIN comments c ON c.object_id = fp.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT created, user_id
             FROM comments 
         ORDER BY created DESC 
            LIMIT 1) AS c2 ON fp.id = c2.object_id
    WHERE fp.deleted != 1
 GROUP BY fp.id
```

*Sorry if you find any errors...I tried whittling this query down to only the relevant parts and I might have made a mistake somewhere in the process*

So basically, what we have here is a table of forum posts and a table of comment replies to those posts. Each forum post can have multiple replies. The first join is used for counting the total number of replies, and the second join is used to get the most recent reply's information. What I get back from this query is something like this:

[image: sample nested query results]

So, I'm basically trying to figure out how I can do this without having to resort to this nested query. Any help you guys can provide would be extremely useful.

Thanks!

**Edit**: I've adjusted the query slightly to reflect the fact that I need to pull back not just the `latest_activity_time`, but also the `latest_activity_user_id`. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
   SELECT fp.id,
          fp.user_id,
          COUNT(a.id) AS num_replies,
          c.date AS latest_activity_time,
          c.user_id AS latest_activity_user_id
     FROM FORUM_POSTS fp
LEFT JOIN COMMENTS a ON a.object_id = fp.id         
LEFT JOIN (SELECT x.object_id,
                  x.date, 
                  x.user_id
             FROM COMMENTS x
             JOIN (SELECT t.object_id,
                          MAX(t.date) AS max_date
                     FROM COMMENTS t
                 GROUP BY t.object_id) y ON y.object_id = x.object_id
                                        AND y.max_date = x.date) b ON b.object_id = fp.id
    WHERE fp.deleted != 1
 GROUP BY fp.id
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @OMG Ponies. I realize now that in my effort to whittle down the query, I took out the most important bit: that I need to grab not only the `latest_activity_time`, but also the user_id and username for that latest activity. Is there a way to do this using MAX(c.date) in the field selections?

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Sorry for the delay. I've adjusted my original question with (hopefully) a more accurate version of the original query. To answer your question directly: yes, the `comments` table has its own `user_id` column.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Thank you, again, for the time that you've put into this. I'm sorry to report that this doesn't appear to work as expected. Using this JOIN does cause the latest_activity_time to come up properly for those posts that have comments, but it eliminates the posts without any comments and it causes the num_replies to always be 1.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Ah ha...indeed, I had tried that, but adding the `LEFT JOIN` instead of the `JOIN` then causes the `latest_activity_time` to be sorted based on id in the `x` table. Basically, the results are the same as those I get using @Mark Bannister's method.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Thanks again! I'm just curious, though...my original query did seem to perform the job with only one nested SELECT, and my question was whether this could be done either without nested SELECTs at all or more efficiently in general. Is yours still more efficient despite having two nested SELECTs?

Comment: @treeface: If this were Oracle 9i+, SQL Server 2005+ or PostgreSQL 8.4+ -- this could be done with one nested SQL, using analytics (ROW_NUMBER).  Your version doesn't return the user & date associated to each post.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: I don't mean to imply that you're wrong, but my original version does appear to bring back exactly what I want. Using just the one nested SELECT, I have it returning the correct values for all the fields. However, I yield to your expertise on the subject...is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @treeface: None taken, but there's no correlation in your query using the LIMIT so I don't see how you can be getting correct results for more than one post -- the last accessed info should be repeating for every post when using your query.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: I don't understand...are you some sort of SQL wizard sent to save me from my own errors? Because it must take some seriously solid understanding of MySQL to see that without having access to my data. You are amazingly amazing. Without your help, this likely would've been a bug that would've taken me hours to sort out. Thank you very much for the time you've spent on this and the explanations you've given to help congeal this idea in my mind.

Comment: @treeface: just a preternatural distaste for the LIMIT clause =)

Answer (score 0):

As you are using MySQL, you should be able to get away with the following:

```
   SELECT fp.id, 
          fp.user_id, 
          COUNT(c.id) AS num_replies, 
          c.created AS latest_activity_time, 
          c.user_id AS latest_activity_user_id
     FROM forum_posts fp
LEFT JOIN comments c ON c.object_id = fp.id
    WHERE fp.deleted != 1
 GROUP BY fp.id
 ORDER BY fp.id, c.created
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this doesn't create the intended result. The comments table is still sorting by the default ID column.